# Ramified primes in radical extension of number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $ K $ be a number field, $ n\ge2$ be a positive integer and  $a \in K^*$.

How does one show 
in the simplest possible way that   a prime ideal $\mathfrak {p}$ of $ K $ not dividing $ n$ is unramified in $ K (\sqrt [n]{a})/K $ if and only if the exact exponent of  $\mathfrak {p}$ in the decomposition in primes ideals of $ a\mathcal{O}_K $ is a multiple of n?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The most important ingredient is copying the question carefully. In particular, make sure that you write unramified when you mean unramified, and that you have included all conditions, such as that the prime ideal must not divide $n$.

Comment: I apologize for my carelessness in copying ! thank you so much for reporting !

Comment: You will find the proof e.g. in Hecke's book on algebraic numbers. As Weil once said, it is difficult to improve on Hecke. If you'd like to do as much as possible yourself, try imitating the case $n = 2$ and $K = {\mathbb Q}$..

Comment: thank you very much ! Can you  tell me the pages I should look at, please? Thanks again !

Comment: Section 39. In case he assumes that the base field contains the n-th roots of unity one needs an additional argument about ramification groups.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the « simplest » proof  consists in passing to the corresponding  extension of local fields, i.e. of the completions $L_w /K_v$ at the (additive) valuations given by the prime ideal $P$ under study.

Choose a $n$-th root $\alpha$ of $a$ .
 If $L_w/K_v$ is unramified,  $n.w(\alpha)= w(a)= v(a)$, so $v(a)$ is a multiple of $n$.

Conversely, suppose that $v(a)$ is a multiple of $n$. Multiplying $a$ by a $n$-th power if necessary, we may assume that $0 \le v(a) \le n – 1$ , so the hypothesis becomes $v(a) = 0$, i.e. $a$ is a $v$-unit. It is classically known that $L_w /K_v$ is unramified iff the relative discriminant $\delta$ of the extension is a $v$-unit (see e.g. Serre’s « Local Fields », chap. III, §5, coroll. 1). Moreover, the discriminant  $\delta$ is the norm of the different $\Delta$, and the latter is the principal ideal generated by $f’(\alpha)$, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$  (op. cit., §7, coroll. 2). Since $f$ divides $X^n – a$, it follows that $f’(\alpha)$ divides $n\alpha^{n-1}$, hence $\delta$ divides the norm of $n\alpha^{n-1}$. Assuming further that $n$ is a $v$-unit, we get that $\delta$ is a $v$-unit, and the extension is unramified.

Note that the assumption that $P$ does not divide $n$ is necessary, because e.g. if $n = p$ := the rational prime under $P$ and $ K_v$ contains a primitive $p$-th root $\zeta$ of 1, it is known that $L_w /K_v$ is unramified iff $v(a – 1) \ge pv(\zeta - 1)  $ (see e.g. exercise 2.12 of Cassels-Fröhlich’s « Algebraic Number Theory »).